# How to fetch raw data from Binance Smart Chain (txs for specific address)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

I am not sure what I don't know and if this is possible. I think this would be a similar issue for Ethereum, so that is the reason why I marked Ethereum on tags.

I am going to describe on example what I want to achieve:

There is a token called "Elonomics".
https://bscscan.com/address/0xd3ecc6a4ce1a9faec1aa5e30b55f8a1a4b84f938

there is owner with address "0x3a78ea5c462f0afa76fa091a70a7bcd020b274d6"
there are all txs from owner address: https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x3a78ea5c462f0afa76fa091a70a7bcd020b274d6

when I take one of the transaction from the owner e.g. 0x6f81f2dbd285d772c6b34151b676f6749ef75ac9a6c76b5e4dfa844a0c6932d2"

I can read the logs from this transaction in:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6f81f2dbd285d772c6b34151b676f6749ef75ac9a6c76b5e4dfa844a0c6932d2#eventlog

so I can read that somebody set "totalSupply :1500000800000"

and now are my questions:

1. Is it possible to fetch all txs related to this specific owner address with these logs in json data (or any other data that can be updated dynamically on dAPPs)?
2. Are data from txs logs are encrypted? (if yes what is the format of this and how to decrypt this how bscscan do)
3. Is it possible to fetch these data directly from blockchain instead of using 3rd part application like bscscan?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to fetch all txs related to this specific owner address with these logs in json data (or any other data that can be updated dynamically on dAPPs)?

Yes, because all this data is stored on a blockchain.

> Are data from txs logs are encrypted? (if yes what is the format of this and how to decrypt this how bscscan do)

All data on a public blockchain is public.

> Is it possible to fetch these data directly from blockchain instead of using 3rd part application like bscscan?

Run your own BSC node. Please see [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library how to interact with an Ethereum based blockchain, like one that is BSC node.